Workday Webservice - Move documents in Compensation Review Statement History
I want to automate a document move via Workday webservice.
Source: Compensation Review Statement History document 
Destination: Personal documents
There is service endpoint(https://wd3-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/<tenant>/Staffing/v43.0) to move documents to Personal documents. But i don't know the service endpoint to get the active worker documents in Compensation Review Statement History. I'm trying to use Compensation review service(https://wd3-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/<tenant>/Compensation_Review/v43.0) Get_Employee_AwardsAsync endpoint and it's empty.
What service endpoint should be used to get documents in Compensation Review Statement History of active workers, not sure which service to use from this catalogue(https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/versions/v43.0/index.html)?
I posted this question in general Workday community and no response. I don't know if there is a dedicated group to post there?

I think what I've seen is similar to Performance reviews, where you need to get the report data source and plug it into the BIRT report design to generate the document.
There is a contributed solution that gets Merit Statements that can be imported. Here is the community link that has more information on that: Attachment Extraction Utility for HCM.
